# Importing RadioTray radio stations into Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, internet-radio

[RadioTray icon applet](http://radiotray.sourceforge.net/) is pretty neat and comes with a variety of predefined radio stations ordered by categories. To those I also added some additional local (Israeli) radio stations and ended up with few dozen.

In preparation for the coming Precise and the need to have one player for all, I would like to migrate this list to Rhythmbox.

The only thing I figured out so far is that the radio stations of Radio Tray are being kept in an XML file at *@HOME/.local/share/radiotray/bookmarks.xml*.

Any ideas how to import RadioTray stations into Rhythmbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The image shows the default RadioTray radio stations imported into Rhythmbox

**How did I do that?**

RadioTray holds its radio-stations in an XML file located in:

```
~/.local/share/radiotray/bookmarks.xml
```

Rhythmbox holds all of its data similarly in an XML file located in:

```
~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml
```

If you examine both files its pretty obvious that the XML format (its defined structure) is very different.

One solution is to *transform* the Radiotray XML format to something that Rhythmbox can understand.

**XSLT**

You can use the structured XML translation language XSLT to perform this conversion.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install python-4suite-xml
```

Next copy the contents below into a new `gedit` file

Save in a file (create the folder `xml` if necessary) called `~/xml/style`

Next, copy the RadioTray XML file to the same folder `~/xml`

Finally, copy the Rhythmbox XML file to the same folder `~/xml`

Drop to a terminal:

```
cd ~/xml
4xslt bookmarks.xml style > test.xml
```

This will reformat the RadioTray into the XML that can be read by RhythmBox

Next we need to add this new data to Rhythmbox.

Now open both `test.xml` and `rhythmdb.xml`

Copy the contents of `test.xml` EXCEPT for the first line into the `rhythmdb.xml` file.  Note - you paste the contents at the end of the file i.e.

```
</entry>

*****paste test.xml here*****

</rhythmdb>
```

Save.

Backup the old `rhythmdb.xml` file and then copy over the new `rhythmdb.xml` file.

Fire up Rhythmbox

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

      <xsl:for-each select="bookmarks/group/group/bookmark">
      <entry type="iradio">
        <title><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></title>
        <genre><xsl:value-of select="translate(../@name,'','')"/></genre>
        <artist></artist>
        <album></album>
    <location><xsl:value-of select="@url"/></location>
        <date>0</date>
        <media-type>application/octet-stream</media-type>
      </entry>
      </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is possible. But, it's not going to be a quick nor fun process.

You'll want to open bookmarks.xml with any program you want (I personally would use gedit) and open Rhythmbox as well. With Rhythmbox open, you'll want to right click "Radio" on the left panel and "New Internet Radio Station". You'll want to copy and paste the url of every radio station that you want to put into Rhythmbox. Then, you can rename them whatever you want to.

You'll have to do this for every one of the urls. It won't take too long, but it's tedious. :(